# After downloading a zip from azure blob storage cant access the zip

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

i have a asp.net core web api controller that is downloading a zip file from azure blob storage using this code.

```
        CloudStorageAccount mycloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = mycloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(azure_ContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filetoDownload);

        FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\Downloads\"+filetoDownload);
        cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(file);
        Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
```

after downloading i am trying to unzip using another controller using this code.

```
        string zipPath = @"D:\Downloads\AUSAssetData_4F3CDD1E-B0B1-4FD9-9663-08B5DE0CE014_DMFPackage.zip";
        string extractPath = @"D:\Downloads\Extracted";
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath, false);
```

But while trying to unzip the file i am getting this error System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file. I want to know is there a way i can stop the previous controller process without stopping the entire service so that my unzip controller can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because your `FileStream` object is still open and has a lock on the file. You will need to close/dispose that object.

Try using the following code:

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(@"D:\Downloads\"+filetoDownload))
{
    await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(file);//You will need to await this process or use DownloadToStream method.
    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
}
```